# How to use copy task with project property in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle file that contains several tasks.

I have a copy task that takes in input a property value taken form the command line.

```
def dir = new File('myDir')

task createDir << {
    dir.mkdirs()
}

task copyFile(dependsOn: createDir, type: Copy){
    from myProperty
    into myDir
}
```

I call gradle like this :

```
gradle -PmyProperty=myInputFile copyFile
```

The problem happens when I have an other independent tasks that don't need `myProperty` to be defined

```
task clean << {
    dir.deleteDir()
}
```

I have the following error

```
$ gradle clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\temp\build.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'temp'.
> Could not find property 'myProperty' on task ':copyFile'.

BUILD FAILED
```

How can I run clean task without needing to provide the missing property ?

P.S. I now that the title of my question is not quite good, but I don't how how I can make it more expressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
task copyFile(dependsOn: createDir, type: Copy){
    from project.hasProperty('myProperty') ? project.myProperty : ''
    into myDir
}
```

The problem arises the property isn't passed. Because this code is run in *configuration* phase You need to substitute it somehow.

Comment: Works in changing project.hasProperty['myProperty'] to project.hasProperty('myProperty')